YA books about a magic bag/ satchel
I think there are 2-3 books in the series. I read them maybe around 2011-2017.
The first book starts out in a war-torn place. There is a satchel given to a person.
Then it jumps to a more modern time where it is gifted to a young girl. She and her friend then have to avoid some bad guys. The satchel turns out to be magical and helps her and her friend to hide in the hay loft in their shed.
In one of the later books the main characters are on a boat and the girl is wearing a yellow bathing suit.
The last thing I remember is that one of the later books takes place in Scotland maybe? In a chateaux and the girl ends up trapped in some kind of prison and the magic bag makes her invisible so she can escape.

You can read the [tour] to learn how to accept an answer (clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons). Wrong answers are an excellent chance to [edit] new details in that you've realized because they don't match the answers.

This may be Gerald Lund's The Guardian series.

When Carruthers "Danni" McAllister receives an antique pouch as a birthday gift from her grandfather, her first reaction is disappointment. "Don't assume that something is empty just because there's nothing there," her grandfather warns. Danni learns that for nearly two hundred years, the mysterious pouch--with its astonishing hidden secrets--as been handed down from generation to generation, and each new owner has had to discover how to access the power it holds, or suffer the penalty of using the pouch unwisely.
While Danni struggles to understand the power of the pouch, her father's discovery of a rhodium mine makes her family the target of a deadly extortionist plot, and the strange pouch is Danni's only hope of saving her family.

The first book opens with her relative fleeing to Paris during World War II. They do hide from bad guys in a hay loft at one point, and the protagonist speculates on it making them invisible.

Now, with the time to think about it, I finally finished that sentence. It was like we were invisible. I shook my head at the sheer impossibility of that, then picked up the pouch and laid it against my cheek. It was still warm, but not hot any longer. Thoughts coursed through my head in a bewildering tumble. I thought of a birthday candle that wouldn’t go out. Of a speed limit sign that toggled back and forth between 65 and 75 miles an hour. Of a sudden, horrible premonition of danger.

Found with a search for site:goodreads.com girl war "magic bag"
